# How do I configure eslint to ignore my root folder and to only include my src folder?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

When I read the eslint docs, it seems like I *should* be able to get it to work with just 1 or 2 lines of code.

You see, here (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#ignorepatterns-in-config-files) they say:

> You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories using `ignorePatterns` in your config files. `ignorePatterns` patterns follow the same rules as `.eslintignore`. Please see the the `.eslintignore` file documentation to learn more.

Well those docs are just a little further down (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#the-eslintignore-file) and there they say:

> Lines preceded by ! are negated patterns that re-include a pattern that was ignored by an earlier pattern.

So, I thought then, that it should work to have this list:

```json
ignorePatterns: ["*", "!src/**/*"]
```

But it doesn't. And I really don't understand why... VSCode stops linting all files, and when I run my `npm run lint` command, I get this message:

> You are linting "src", but all of the files matching the glob pattern "src" are ignored.

Oh and just to prevent misunderstandings, I don't need this for my `npm run lint` command. Because in that command I can already configure eslint to only look into my `src` folder. The reason I want to get these `ignorePatterns` to work like I described is because I want VSCode to stop trying to lint files that are outside my src folder.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I managed to get it to work. I read on another stackoverflow thread that if you start a pattern with a slash, that it will automatically mean that that pattern will start from the root folder and as long as you don't add any `**` into the pattern, it also won't go any deeper than the root folder.

So for example: `"*"` can mean any file or folder anywhere in the project. But `"/*"` can only mean any file or folder in the root of the project.

And then I also read the following on [the git docs about gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> An optional prefix `"!"` which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

(emphasis mine)

So before when I did this previously: `ignorePatterns: ["*", "!src/**/*"]`, it didn't work because the `"*"` matches every file and folder everywhere, including all the parents of every file and folder in `src`. Which means that I couldn't re-include them.

Anyway, the fix was therefor fairly easy. Namely, this:

```json
ignorePatterns: ["/*", "!/src"]
```

Because `"/*"` matches all files and folders in the root folder (but not the root folder itself), and so no parent of `src` was already ignored and therefor I am allowed to re-include `src` with `"!/src"`.